# Lua: function as argument of function

Tags: function, lua, arguments

Is it possible write a function as a function argument?
Let me explain: this is my code

```
table = {
    yellow = {
        "banana",
        "lemon"
    },
    red = {
        "apple"
        },
    green = {
        "watermelon"
        }
}

function fruit(arg1) print(arg1) end

function scope(tbl, func)
  for k, v in pairs(tbl) do
    
    if (type(v) ~= "table") then
      func(v)
    else
      scope(v)
    end
    
  end
end

scope(table,fruit)
```

My output should be

- banana
- lemon
- apple
- watermelon

This is the error message

> local 'func' is not callable (a nil value)

Comment: Yes, it's possible. You just forgot to pass the `func` argument to `scope`

Comment: In this way? `function scope(tbl, func(arg1))`

Comment: @user3713179 They are referring to the nested call in `scope`, the one that says `scope(v)`

Answer (score 1):

When `scope` calls `scope` you forgot to pass the argument `func` so it is nil.

```
scope(v)
```

is the same as

```
scope(v, nil)
```

while you probably meant

```
scope(v, func)
```